# After Installation: Wordpress can't find url. But can open certain files

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am encountering a problem with wordpress. Until now I have set up quite some installations, but this time I get a weird error.

I installed WP on a remote Server in an existent database, that already contains 2 wp-installations with different table-prefixes. The new installation of course got a differing prefix.
The new installation was made in a subfolder on the server:

```
www.theUrl.com/wp/<wp_files...>
```

The URL directs to a subfolder ("my_new_site" in the example underneath) on the server. Inside this subfolder I created the folder "wp" where I put all the wp-files.

```
root-dir
|-> existing_wp1
|-> existingwp_wp2
|-> my_new_site
    |-> wp
         |-> <wordpress-files...>
```

The whole installation prosess of wp worked as usual and I got redirected to the login-page. But after logging in, i get the Error:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /wp/wp-admin/ was not found on this server.

phpMyAdmin shows me, that the tables with the specified prefix were created. Trying to open the index.php-file directly is causing nearly the same error, mentioning, that "/wp/" was not found.
However I can access wp-login and readme.html. FileZilla is showing me, that all files are correctly uploaded.

I absolutely have no idea where to start searching for a solution, because the directories are evidently existent.

EDIT: changed the url to: www.theUrl.com/wp/ and added information on the directory-structure

Comment: did you open example.com/subfolder/wp/ or example.com/subfolder/ ?

Comment: Have you set the `siteurl` and `home` to include your subdirectory? (in the `wp_options` table)

Comment: Yes I think so. Both options do have the value http://www.theUrl.com/wp. Please note my changes to the main posting.